# x11vnc can not authenticate from LAN in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, vnc, vnc-server, vnc-viewer

I am using x11vnc in ubuntu 20.04, in one of my machine, I can not authenticate VNC client from LAN computer's VNC viewer. in same machine (localhost) it is working fine.

here is my configration file **/lib/systemd/system/x11vnc.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=x11vnc service
After=display-manager.service network.target syslog.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -forever -display :0 -auth guess
ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall x11vnc
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

with the same configuration in another machine, it is working fine. I double check ufw rules. I tried to set a password in this configuration file as well but nothing works for me.